# using etc. with a list in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following correct?

> If the item is unknown, pending, unavailable, etc. please talk to your administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it needs a comma after the period of etc.

Comment: I had that at first and the I took it away! Thanks

Comment: Strip the list down to one element. If you need a comma, then you need a comma after the last element in the list. I.E., "If the item is unknown, please call..." Ergo, you need the comma after the etc. The period remains because it's an abbreviation.

Comment: Good advice, @DrRandy!

Answer (score 0):

If *etc.* were followed by a comma, most people would consider that grammatical.

Being extremely pedantic, the phrase ***et*** *cetera* means "**and** others", which is the wrong conjunction in this context.  You could instead use *vel sim.*, an abbreviation of the Latin phrase "vel similia" meaning "...or similar".  I wouldn't seriously suggest this, of course, since very few people would recognise that term and none would be confused by your failure to use it.

However, this does serve as yet another reason to think twice before using *etc*.  Why not simply list all the cases in which the reader should talk to their administrator?  Are there any, other than the ones listed?